# Facebook style micro publsher

Tags: views

I have been implemented [Facebook style micro publsher](http://drupal.org/project/fbsmp) in my project and now i can post text/media as like Facebook while updating status. Now i need to create a view that contains all posts from every user in a single page . How can i create a view like that ?

Comment: Did you check the view provided by that module by default ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a default view to get all statuses **(D7)**

This is the path */admin/structure/views/view/statuses_all/edit*

[image]

Comment: @Nikhil My Pleasure.

Comment: That's what I already answered :)

Comment: @NikhilM going slightly off-topic, but which tool do you use to taking snapshots and/or editing the images? They look cool :-)

Comment: @indrock, Here is it http://bit.ly/QrKEiq, and give me up-vote `;)`

Comment: @NikhilM - thanks for the share. You have my +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

There is an default view called **statuses_all/facebook_status_all(D6)** in statuses/facebook_status(D6) module itself, You can use that one.

When you're enabling FBSMP module it will automatically add [FBSMP themed attachment field](http://drupalcode.org/project/fbsmp.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/fbsmp.module#l1521) to all the default views of Statuses/facebook_status(D6). So that view will list down all the statuses with media(If its available.)

Comment: First off, an answer that is accepted from the OP is not a correct answer: It is just the answer that helped the OP. Accepting an answer is a rather subjective act; just the OP can know which of the answers helped her/him the most, or if the only existing answer helped her/him in some way. http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/a/2200/4471

Comment: I never said anything about accepting/down vote/up vote, just mentioned that same answer is already posted :). Watch the words before posting.

Comment: I am sure there is no limit for answers here. see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq